# Using <pre> in function in PHP

Tags: php, function

I want to be able to print arrays and json results with php using html `<pre>` tag.

Today - everytime I do this I do like this

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($value_to_print);
echo '<pre>';
```

Now finally understanding a bit more about functions I realize I soon need to say goodbye to copy - paste. Anyhow - back to the problem. I want to make a function out of the above but I can't get it to work.

```
function prefunc($value_to_print){

$ret = '<pre>'; 
$ret .= print_r($value_to_print); 
$ret .= '</pre>';

return $ret;
}

prefunc($print_this_within_pre_tags);
```

New to functions - please help me get rid of copy paste and sloppy code :D

Thank you

Comment: `echo $ret;` instead of `return $ret;`.

Comment: or `echo prefunc($print_this_within_pre_tags);`

Comment: @u_mulder didnt do the trick. Result was only returning print_r($value_to_print) and then the echo returned 1

Comment: @aynber same result there - the function is frinted first then returns 1

Comment: I should mention that $value_to_print is an array

Comment: OH! [print_r prints to the screen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) UNLESS you pass `true` in as the second parameter